# using list's newform.aspx as a webpart

Tags: web-part, list

I want that the newform.aspx of the list would be in a webpart page,
meaning that when I call the page there will be a webpart in it which will show just the newform.aspx inside it....

can this be done with listviewwebpart ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use the PageViewer webpart! It is designed to show another page in it (basically in an iframe) [Documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx)

Comment: regarding the same issue
is the ListFormWebPart good for this purpose too ?

Comment: Sure it is! This blogpost might be helpful http://www.lucacostante.com/item/12-empty-list-item-values-when-using-a-listformwebpart.html